# How to you get the last inserted ID with a raw query using Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

When trying the following raw MySQL insert in sequelize.js:

```
mysql_sequelize.query( 'INSERT IGNORE INTO steamer(steamer_id, prov_id, name, avatar) VALUES(UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(),\'-\',\'\')), \'' + prov_id + '\', \'' + steamer_name + '\', \'' + steamer_avatar + '\')')
  .then(function (data) {
       console.log('inserted STEAMER data---> ',data);  // no useful info
  });
);
```

The resulting console log looks like the following:

```
inserted STEAMER data--->  [ OkPacket {
    fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 1,
    insertId: 0,
    serverStatus: 2,
    warningCount: 1,
    message: '',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0 },
  OkPacket {
    fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 1,
    insertId: 0,
    serverStatus: 2,
    warningCount: 1,
    message: '',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0 } ]
```

What do I have to do to get following data's ID? or even the last inserted ID?

Comment: 1 year later, sorry Iam late :D

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this by passsing `{ type: sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT }` as a option argument. This will make sequelize return the insert it.

Simple query example:

```
sequelize.query(
    "INSERT INTO clients (name) values ('myClient')",
    { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT }
).then(function (clientInsertId) {
    console.log(clientInsertId);
});
```

Comment: for postgresql, you need to include "RETURNING id"